# Adverb position: 'I have also been working" or 'I have been also working'?

Tags: adverb-position

I doubt about the place of the adverb 'also' in the following sentence:
'I work at the hospital, and for three years I have also been working for my PhD at the University.'
Should I say: 'I have been also working'?
Could you help me?
Best regards

Comment: The first phrasing (*also been*) is correct. You'll also probably want to say "working *on* my PhD" (as opposed to *for*). You might also like to check out our sister site, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @DanBron; I disagree. Working for a degree is a much more common expression than working on a degree.

Comment: @Chenmunka, not in my experience (US universities).

Comment: Using "also" AND "and" seems unnecessary to me. You could use "I work at the hospital; also, for three years I have been working for my PhD at the University."

Comment: It's unclear.  Have you been working a second job to pay for your PhD expenses?

Answer (score 2):

see the comparison from google. [google book Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+been+also%2Chave+also+been%2Calso+have+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20also%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20also%20been%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calso%20have%20been%3B%2Cc0)!

[image: usage comparison from google]

Comment: You're allowed up to 5 words, so you could eliminate arguably different forms such as 'I have also been to the Isle of Man'.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no difference in meaning, but "have also been working" is the order in which the ear typically expects to hear those words expressed. Still, no one would be confused if you got it the other way around.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest it should read, "I also have been working..."

Comment: Can you explain why you're suggesting this over the other options?

Comment: That sounds as though someone else has been working on it and you, also, have been working on it. For example "John has been working on the project full time for six years, I, also, have been working on it for the past two years but only in my spare time".